# Rename all columns except id column by adding a prefix using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I have a dataframe with columns id, feature_1, feature_2, feature_3 as follows.

```
df = data.frame(
  id = sample(letters, 5),
  feature_1 = sample(1:10, 5),
  feature_2 = runif(5),
  feature_3 = rnorm(5)
)
```

I want to rename all the feature columns by adding a prefix. The following line doesn't work and output error.

```
df %>%
  rename_with(~(ifelse(names(.x) == "id", paste0("source_", names(.x)), "id")))

Error in names[cols] <- .fn(names[cols], ...) : 
  replacement has length zero
```

Any hint on how to modify this? What does .x represent inside rename_with? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rename_with(~ paste0("source_", .), -id)
```

The third argument to `rename_with` is `.cols`, where you can use [tidyselect](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/) syntax to select the columns. Here `-id` excludes this column.

---

Per the comments the `.` syntax is a cleaner/simpler style than an writing an anonymous function, but you could accomplish this equivalently as:

```
df %>% 
  rename_with(function(x) paste0("source_", x), -id)

# R >= 4.1.0
df %>% 
  rename_with(\(x) paste0("source_", x), -id)
```

Comment: Thanks LMc! What does the dot represent inside rename_with? I notice some dplyr functions use dot and some others use .x. What are the differences between them?

Comment: The dot syntax refers to the column over which the function is being applied. Either `.` or `.x` will be recognized as this reference.

Comment: For rename_with, it seems the dot represents the column name? If I change the command to ```df %>% rename_with(~(ifelse(.x == "id", paste0("source_", .x), "id")))```, it doesn't work either.

Comment: In this specific function, but more generally that's what the dots represent. For example `df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("feature"), ~ . + 1))` the dot does not represent the column name.

Comment: Thanks LMc! For my purposes I needed to exclude multiple columns using column id, so here's the syntax in case others need it.

`df %>% rename_with(~ paste0("source_", .), .cols = -c(1:2,4))`

Answer (score 1):

```
names(df) <- paste0("Source_", names(df))
```

This is a model for the solution.  To apply the modification to a subset of names, use indexing, as in

```
i <- grep("feature", names(df))
names(df)[i] <-  paste0("Source_", names(df)[i])
```

Here, `i` is an array of indexes of the names to modify.  It doesn't matter how it's created, but `grep` is a great way to do so when the criterion is based on the name itself.

Comment: Thanks whuber! I'm curious about the implementation in dplyr using pipe format r code and the functionality of .x passing inside rename_with function.

Comment: That seems like (at best) a roundabout way of doing something that is simple and directly supported in base `R`.